# Angular 9: Fork join with array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to make multiple API request to an endpoint in which the values are iterated over an array

So I used  rxjs `forkJoin` to achieve this

```
//array to keep obeserbles
propOb: Observable<any>[];

input.property.forEach(property => {
         console.log('prop', property);
         const t = this.baseApiService.sendRequest(
          'json',
          {
           method: 'post',
           endPoint: 'v1/property/new',
           data: {
              property_id: uuid.v4(),
              ics_ref_no: '122',
              property_type: property.type,
              property_role: property.role,
              property_dec: property.description,
              
           }
         });
         this.propOb.push(t);
         });

    forkJoin(this.propOb).subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data);
    });
```

While running i am getting the following error `cannot read property 'push' of undefined` from  this line `this.propOb.push(t);`

Also, I'm not sure my approach is correct or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the array. It's has 'undefined' type until you do so.

change

```
propOb: Observable<any>[];
```

to

```
propOb: Observable<any>[] = [];
```